# React destructuring state to pass into component props

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am passing in part of my state into component props like this:

```js
<EditBoard
  boardArr={{
    boardid: this.state.boardid,
    boardvalue: this.state.boardvalue,
    boardcolor: this.state.boardcolor,
  }}
/>
```

This works but I understand this is not the best way to go. Wondering how I might destructure this in a more elegant way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Destructuring this way works, and also you don't need to do `key: key`. I'd say, do this way:

```js
  const { boardid, boardvalue, boardcolor } = this.state;

  return (
    <div>
      <EditBoard
        boardArr={{
          boardid,
          boardvalue,
          boardcolor
        }}
      />
    </div>
  );
```

Comment: Thanks! that definitely works. I was attempting to destructure in the prop and it didn't work out well.

Comment: @dangre00 Let me know if you need further help. Happy to provide you a hand.

Comment: Is there a way to scope the destructure to the prop itself through a function? I want to avoid potential conflicts of declaring these variables elsewhere. Thanks so much for your help!

Comment: @dangre00 Can you show me a sample code using CodeSandbox or something, happy to look into it. With what you said, I feel the answer will be same as `const { prop1, prop2, prop3 } = this.props`...

Comment: @dangre00 Or if you're using a functional component, what you can do is: `const Comp = ({ prop1, prop2, prop3 }) => (<div> ... </div>);`. Does this help?

Comment: Here's what I'm trying to accomplish, but it doesn't seem to quite work! https://codesandbox.io/s/wizardly-bas-bc24y?file=/src/App.js

Comment: @dangre00 Checking.

Comment: @dangre00 Functions aren't displayed in `JSON.stringify()`. What doesn't work here?

Comment: @dangre00 Also, you forgot to call the function: https://codesandbox.io/s/inspiring-violet-7s9oh?file=/src/App.js It works flawless!  Please check the output here: https://7s9oh.csb.app/

Comment: I was just trying to pass that destructured array into the prop, but I'm not sure if that will work the way I'm doing it. If I uncomment your code it works just fine so I think I'll stick with that. Thanks again!

Comment: Of course! That works to call the function. Thank you again!!!! I really appreciate your help. I'm very new to all this :)

Comment: @dangre00 Sure, and anytime, if you wanna talk to me, my contact details are in my profile page. Or at https://praveen.science/

Comment: Thank you, Praveen!